# Why don't need to use free() function in this case?

Tags: c, malloc, free

So it'is a simple code. I won't explain it further. My problem is, if I use `free()` it cause an

> *** Error in `./main': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffee58389f8 *** error,

but I am not exactly understand why. It is because I gave a loop variable address to the ptr? If I remove `free()` function call, it works perfectly, but I am curious what cause this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Give me a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * num);

  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  {
    ptr = &i;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
  }
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr = &i;` You have changed the `ptr` to point to `i`. That `i` variable is not heap (dynamic) memory and thus cannot be freed. What exactly are you intending to do there?

Comment: Just playing around with pointers nothing specific. Thanks the answer. :)

Comment: Ok, but even just logically it doesn't make sense. It's like doing `a = 1; a = 2;`. Clearly the first value is lost by overwriting with the second value. In this case it is the `malloc` value that is lost so there is no possible way for that to be freed.

Comment: Yes I knew that, just trying things out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs):

> Definitely lost". This means that no pointer to the block can be
> found. The block is classified as "lost", because the programmer could
> not possibly have freed it at program exit, since no pointer to it
> exists. This is likely a symptom of having lost the pointer at some
> earlier point in the program. Such cases should be fixed by the
> programmer.

In the code, pointer to the malloc'ed memory has been modified (`ptr = &i`) So, we lost the pointer to the memory.
And, you shouldn't free stack memory.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer value you pass to `free` *must* be a value returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.  In this case you reassigned `ptr` with the address of `i`, which was *not* the result of a `*alloc` call.  Note that in the process you lost your only reference to the dynamically-allocated memory, so you don’t have a way to free it later; this is known as a memory leak.

You get the same problem if you do something like `ptr++` - you’re still pointing within the dynamically-allocated block, but again it’s not the address returned by `*alloc` so you get the same error.